# "sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly" must be set error in sonarqube 5.0.1

Tags: c#, msbuild, sonarqube, fxcop

We are using: SonarQube 5.0, MSBuild Sonar Runner 1.1 C# plugin 4.4, and jdk 1.8.

While running the analysis with FxCop Rules enabled we get the following error:

> The property "sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly" must be set and the project must have been built to execute FxCop rules.
>   This property can be automatically set by the Analysis Bootstrapper for Visual Studio Projects plugin, see: http://docs.codehaus.org/x/TAA1Dg.
>   If you wish to skip the analysis of not built projects, set the property "sonar.visualstudio.skipIfNotBuilt".

What I've done:

I have installed FxCop 10.0. We are using Windows Server 2008 R2. We are not using any database.

My major concern is that if I deactivate all my FxCop rules, then my Sonar works; but if I activate them, I get the above error.

Questions:

What should I do after installing FxCop? What extra configurations are needed if I want Sonar to run with FxCop.

With Sonar-runner 2.5 installed, where can I setup MS-build scanner to analyze .NET? Please tell me what must be set in `sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly`, I am confused here.

Do we need to install VS2010 or a different version? Do we need to install any VS plugins?

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to configure `sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly` with the path to FxCop. You can do that on the command line (`-Dsonar.cs.fxcop.assembly=xxx`) or via the GUI.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I will try it but do we have separate fxcop plugin that supports 5.0.1?Is it mandatory to install vstudio?

Comment: Just one thing we cant use sonar properties in this configuration then where should i put sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly property?

Comment: You can configure it in the GUI

Comment: Thanks Ann ,The answer for this error is we have to install MSbuild 14.0 in Envt variables and install VS2015 which will remove this error easily.